# What is the cloudwatch insights logs equivalent of SQL's "WHERE IN ('foo', 'bar')"

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

This is not valid:

```
fields @timestamp, log
| sort @timestamp desc
| filter kubernetes.pod_name like /my-pod/
| filter log.someId IN (156446, 156447, 156448, 156449, 156450, 156451, 156453, 156454, 156455, 156456, 156457, 156458, 156459, 156460, 156461, 156462, 154832, 154379, 154380, 154381, 154382, 153597, 145666, 145647, 145627, 139961, 139967, 142303, 142597, 130045, 129441, 131003, 123103, 122227, 122294 )
```

the last part is not correct. What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Just use `[]` instead of `()`. So:

```
fields @timestamp, log
| sort @timestamp desc
| filter kubernetes.pod_name like /my-pod/
| filter log.someId IN [156446, 156447, 156448, 156449, 156450, 156451, 156453, 156454, 156455, 156456, 156457, 156458, 156459, 156460, 156461, 156462, 154832, 154379, 154380, 154381, 154382, 153597, 145666, 145647, 145627, 139961, 139967, 142303, 142597, 130045, 129441, 131003, 123103, 122227, 122294]
```